# dynamic forms multiple input fields calculate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I need to add form fields dynamically. Each group of input values contain 3 fields, `quantity`, `price`, and `total`. Every time I insert numeric values to `quantity` and `price` the field `total` must show the sum or multiply.

I have realized this but it works only on the first field. When I add another row of fields it doesn't calculate others.

Here is my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 1;
    $('#add').click(function() {
     i++;
     $('#articles').append('<tr id="row' + i + '"><td><input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity[]" placeholder="quantity" class="form-control name_list" /></td> <td><input type="number" id="price" name="price[]" placeholder="price" class="form-control name_list" /></td> <td><input type="number" id="total" name="total[]" placeholder="total" class="form-control name_list" readonly /></td> <td><button type="button" name="remove" id="' + i + '" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function() {
     var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
     $('#row' + button_id + '').remove();
    });

    $('#submit').click(function() {
     //alert($('#add_name').serialize()); //alerts all values and works fine          
     $.ajax({
      url: "wwwdb.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: $('#add_name').serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
       $('#add_name')[0].reset();
      }
     });
    });

    function upd_art() {
     var qty = $('#quantity').val();
     var price = $('#price').val();
     var total = (qty * price).toFixed(2);
     $('#total').val(total);
    }
    setInterval(upd_art, 1000);
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <br />
    <br />
    <h2 align="center">title</h2>
    <div class="form-group">
      <form name="add_name" id="add_name">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-bordered" id="articles">
            <tr>

              <td><input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity[]" placeholder="quantity" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" id="price" name="price[]" placeholder="price" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
              <td><input type="number" id="total" name="total[]" placeholder="total" class="form-control name_list" readonly /></td>
              <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add new</button></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: for starters, ids have to be unique

Comment: this script works fine when i insert values to database. The goal is to not insert the value total manually but to calculate it automatically and then save to db.
If possible any example on how to figure with unique ids in this case. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution:

FIRST: Added JQuery

SECOND: Corrected the method to calculate. It should multiply instead of making sum if you want quantity * price.  Review my changes

THIRD: Added a number on each ID and in the append method.

FOURTH: Changed calculate method to carry the id

THIRD: Commented the timer you created, and called the method that calculates the final value inside the [JQUERY event "change"](https://api.jquery.com/change/) of the inputs. This way, you are not processing forever (even when nothing changed) and it´s only calculated when the `change` event is fired

Hope it helps

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 0;
  $("#quantity-" + i).change(function() {
    upd_art(i)
  });
  $("#price-" + i).change(function() {
    upd_art(i)
  });


  $('#add').click(function() {
    i++;
    $('#articles').append('<tr id="row' + i + '"><td><input type="number" value=0 id="quantity-' + i + '" name="quantity[]" placeholder="quantity" class="form-control name_list" /></td> <td><input type="number" id="price-' + i + '" name="price[]" value=0  placeholder="price" class="form-control name_list" /></td> <td><input type="number" id="total-' + i + '" name="total[]" placeholder="total" class="form-control name_list" readonly /></td> <td><button type="button" name="remove" id="' + i + '" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');

    $("#quantity-" + i).change(function() {
      upd_art(i)
    });
    $("#price-" + i).change(function() {
      upd_art(i)
    });


  });


  $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function() {
    var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
    $('#row' + button_id + '').remove();
  });

  $('#submit').click(function() {
    alert($('#add_name').serialize()); //alerts all values           
    $.ajax({
      url: "wwwdb.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: $('#add_name').serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        $('#add_name')[0].reset();
      }
    });
  });

  function upd_art(i) {
    var qty = $('#quantity-' + i).val();
    var price = $('#price-' + i).val();
    var totNumber = (qty * price);
    var tot = totNumber.toFixed(2);
    $('#total-' + i).val(tot);
  }



  //  setInterval(upd_art, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <br />
    <br />
    <h2 align="center">title</h2>
    <div class="form-group">
      <form name="add_name" id="add_name">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-bordered" id="articles">
            <tr class="rrjeshta">

              <td><input value=0 type="number" id="quantity-0" name="quantity[]" placeholder="quantity" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
              <td><input value=0 type="number" id="price-0" name="price[]" placeholder="price" class="form-control name_list" /></td>

              <td><input type="number" id="total-0" name="total[]" placeholder="total" class="form-control name_list" readonly /></td>
              <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add new</button></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: u welcome!! ;) . Saw that the first row does not change "after" creating seconds or thirds. Maybe needs further checking, but the idea on how to use ids on jquery is this way. 

Anyway, strongly recommend using angularJs for those thins ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should use unique `id` attributes in one DOM. When same `ids` are present in one HTML, and you use them in jquery, only first occurances of the id will be considered and it will not work as expected.

use `class` instead `id` when you make new dynamic elements. and use class selector in jquery function `upd_art`.