# insert calculator inside jQuery .on() “append”

Tags: jquery, calculator

newbie here. I have a script that calculates the quantity and the price.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#quantity_1,#product_price_1').on('input',function() {
        var quantity_1 = parseInt($('#quantity_1').val());
        var product_price_1 = parseFloat($('#product_price_1').val());
        $('#total_cost_1').val((product_price_1 * quantity_1  ? product_price_1 * quantity_1 : 0).toFixed(2));
      });

      $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#calculate_1").click(function() {
              var rate = parseInt($('#rate_1').val());;
              var total_cost = parseInt($('#total_cost_1').val());
              var total_rate = rate * total_cost;
              $('#total_cost_1').val((total_rate).toFixed(2));
          });
      });
    </script>
```

In my HTML table I have another jquery script that adds new HTML row. My problem now is i can't add the calculator script to the new generated HTML row.

Here's the HTML code of the table

```
        <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th><input class='check_all' type='checkbox' onclick="select_all()"/></th>
            <th>Product Code</th>
            <th>Product name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Rate</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Total Cost</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type='checkbox' class='chkbox'/></td>
            <td><input class="form-control autocomplete_txt" type='text' data-type="product_code" id='product_code_1' name='product_code[]'/></td>
            <td><input class="form-control autocomplete_txt" type='text' data-type="product_name" id='product_name_1' name='product_name[]'/> </td>
            <td><input class="form-control" type='number' data-type="product_price" id='product_price_1' name='product_price[]' onkeyup="AutoCalc(this)"/></td> <!-- purchase_cost -->
            <td style="width: 150px;">
              <input class="form-control" type='number' id='rate_1' name='rate[]' min='0' step='0.1' style="width: 99px; float: left;" />
              <button type="button" id="calculate_1" class="btn btn-sm btn-dark btn-icon" data-toggle="tooltip" title="calculate with rate value" style="width: 20px; float: left;"><i class="fas fa-calculator"></i></button>
            </td>
            <td><input class="form-control" type='number' id='quantity_1' name='quantity[]' onkeyup="AutoCalc(this)"/> </td>
            <td><input class="form-control" type='text' class="subtotal" id='total_cost_1' name='total_cost[]'/> </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      <input class="form-control" type='hidden' data-type="product_id_1" id='product_id_1' name='product_id[]'/>            
      <button type="button" class='btn btn-danger delete'>- Delete</button>
      <button type="button" class='btn btn-success addbtn'>+ Add More</button>
```

Once the +add more button is pressed it calls this script which add new row

```
var i=$('table tr').length;
$(".addbtn").on('click',function(){
  count=$('table tr').length;
    var data="<tr><td><input type='checkbox' class='chkbox'/></td>";
      data+="<td><input class='form-control autocomplete_txt' type='text' data-type='product_code' id='product_code_"+i+"' name='product_code[]'/></td>";
      data+="<td><input class='form-control autocomplete_txt' type='text' data-type='product_name' id='product_name_"+i+"' name='product_name[]'/></td>";
      data+="<td><input class='form-control' type='number' data-type='product_price' id='product_price_"+i+"' name='product_price[]'/></td>";
      data+="<input class='form-control' type='hidden' data-type='product_id' id='product_id_"+i+"' name='product_id[]'/>";
      data+="<td><input class='form-control' type='number' id='rate_"+i+"' name='rate[]'  min='0' step='0.5' style='width: 99px; float: left;'/><button type='button' id='calculate_1' class='btn btn-sm btn-dark btn-icon' data-toggle='tooltip' title='calculate with rate value' style='width: 20px; float: left;''><i class='fas fa-calculator'></i></button></td>";
      data+="<td><input class='form-control' type='number' id='quantity_"+i+"' name='quantity[]'/> </td>";
      data+="<td><input class='form-control' type='text' class='subtotal'  id='total_cost_"+i+"' name='total_cost[]'/> </td></tr>";
  $('table').append(data);
  i++;
});
```

**my question is how can I add the first script(the calculator) i mention to the last code above?**

Comment: Please add the HTML code.

Comment: Hi @TatendaZifudzi I just edit my question.

Comment: You mention a for loop but I don't see one in your code. Regardless, if you want to attach event listeners to elements that are added to the DOM dynamically, you have to do it after their added. In other words, call the `on` method after you call the `append` method. It will probably behoove you to wrap your calculator logic in a function outside of the loop and simply reference it as the event handler. Good luck!

Comment: there I reconstruct my question and change the title. still I don't know what to do please guys. thanks

Comment: i tried to add this           $('#quantity_'+i+', #product_price_'+i+'').on('input',function() {
            var quantity = parseInt($('#quantity_'+i+'').val());
            var product_price = parseFloat($('#product_price_'+i+'').val());
            $('#total_cost_'+i+'').val((product_price * quantity  ? product_price * quantity : 0).toFixed(2));
          }); before $('table').append(data); but did not work

Comment: Found this link which solve my issues, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46114032/dynamic-forms-multiple-input-fields-calculate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi to all newbie like me. If it happens you were tasked to do such project like this, here's the snippet. it already has comma in numbers like 123,456,789. Thanks to these guys, @OliverTrampleasure, @20yco and @Haldo

```js
var rowCount = 1;
  
  $('#add').click(function() {
    rowCount++;
    $('#orders').append('<tr id="row'+rowCount+'"><td><input class="form-control product_price" type="number" data-type="product_price" id="product_price_'+rowCount+'" name="product_price[]" for="'+rowCount+'"/></td><input class="form-control" type="hidden" data-type="product_id" id="product_id_'+rowCount+'" name="product_id[]" for="'+rowCount+'"/><td><input class="form-control quantity" type="number" class="quantity" id="quantity_'+rowCount+'" name="quantity[]" for="'+rowCount+'"/> </td><td><input class="form-control total_cost" type="text" id="total_cost_'+rowCount+'" name="total_cost[]"  for="'+rowCount+'" readonly/> </td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+rowCount+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove cicle">-</button></td></tr>');
});

// Add a generic event listener for any change on quantity or price classed inputs
$("#orders").on('input', 'input.quantity,input.product_price', function() {
  getTotalCost($(this).attr("for"));
});

$(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function() {
  var button_id = $(this).attr('id');
  $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();
});

// Using a new index rather than your global variable i
function getTotalCost(ind) {
  var qty = $('#quantity_'+ind).val();
  var price = $('#product_price_'+ind).val();
  var totNumber = (qty * price);
  // .toLocaleString
  var tot = totNumber.toLocaleString("en-US", { maximumFractionDigits: 2});
  $('#total_cost_'+ind).val(tot);
  calculateSubTotal();
}

function calculateSubTotal() {
  var subtotal = 0;
  $('.total_cost').each(function() {
                                       // replace ',' here
     subtotal += parseFloat($(this).val().replace(/,/g,''));
  });
  // toLocaleString
  $('#subtotal').val(subtotal.toLocaleString("en-US", { maximumFractionDigits: 2}));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="line line-dashed line-lg pull-in"></div>
          <div class="row">
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="orders">
              <tr>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Total Cost</th>
                <th>
                </th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input class="form-control product_price" type='number' data-type="product_price" id='product_price_1' name='product_price[]' for="1"/></td> <!-- purchase_cost -->
                <td><input class="form-control quantity" type='number' id='quantity_1' name='quantity[]' for="1"/></td>
                <td><input class="form-control total_cost" type='text' id='total_cost_1' name='total_cost[]' for='1' readonly/></td>
                <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success circle">+</button></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <input class="form-control" type='hidden' data-type="product_id_1" id='product_id_1' name='product_id[]'/>            
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="line line-dashed line-lg pull-in" style="clear: both;"></div>
        
        <div class="col-md-12 nopadding">
          <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 pull-right nopadding">
            <div class="col-md-8 pull-right nopadding">
              <div class="form-group">
                <td><input class="form-control subtotal" type='text' id='subtotal' name='subtotal' readonly/></td>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 pull-right">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Subtotal</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```